# Doesn't show the Chart

Tags: javascript, php, phpmyadmin, google-visualization

I have a problem showing the the pie chart. Seems like the sql is fine because i tried it on the database itself and it works perfectly. I conclude that the chart was the problem of not showing the pie. I cant figure out what's the problem. Thank you very much ..................................................

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitbttn'])){

    $dFrom = $_POST['dateFrom'];
    $dTo = $_POST['dateTo'];

 ?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['District', '<?php echo $dFrom;?> <?php echo $dTo;?> Dengue'],
          ['North',     

          <?php
                    mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //phpmyadmin username and pass
                    mysql_select_db("lcho_login"); //your database name needs to access

                    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(`deng_case_ind1`) AS ind_num FROM lcho_dengue_cases2 WHERE `date` between '". $dFrom ."' and '".$dTo."' ");

                    $indicator10='ind_num'; // name column in the table
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

                      echo $row['ind_num'];

                    }
                ?>

          ],

          ['South',      

          <?php
                     $sql=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(`deng_case_ind2`) AS ind_num FROM lcho_dengue_cases2 WHERE `date` between '". $dFrom ."' and '".$dTo."' ");

                    $indicator10='ind_num'; // name column in the table
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

                      echo $row['ind_num'];

                    }
                ?>

          ],
          ['East',  

          <?php
                   $sql=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(`deng_case_ind3`) AS ind_num FROM lcho_dengue_cases2 WHERE `date` between '". $dFrom ."' and '".$dTo."' ");

                    $indicator10='ind_num'; // name column in the table
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

                      echo $row['ind_num'];

                    }
                ?>

          ],
          ['West', 

          <?php
                    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(`deng_case_ind4`) AS ind_num FROM lcho_dengue_cases2 WHERE `date` between '". $dFrom ."' and '".$dTo."' ");

                    $indicator10='ind_num'; // name column in the table
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

                      echo $row['ind_num'];

                    }
                ?>

          ],
          ['Urban',    

          <?php
                     $sql=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(`deng_case_ind5`) AS ind_num FROM lcho_dengue_cases2 WHERE `date` between '". $dFrom ."' and '".$dTo."' ");

                    $indicator10='ind_num'; // name column in the table
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

                      echo $row['ind_num'];

                    }
                ?>

          ]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Lipa City dengue as of <?php echo $dFrom;?>.'to' .<?php echo $dTo; ?>',

          is3D: true,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="page-header float-center">
                <div class="page-title">
                    <form action="#" method="post">
          <div class="container">

    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="dateFrom">From: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="date" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom">

        </div>
    </div>
```

```
            <label for="dateTo">To: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="date" id="dateTo" name="dateTo">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Continue

```
        </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


    </div>



        <?php if(isset($_POST['submitbttn'])){


            $dFrom = $_POST['dateFrom']; //get input text
            $dTo = $_POST['dateTo']; //get input text


            $text = "<h1>Dengue Summary</br> Lipa City || ". $dFrom . " ".$dTo." </h1>";

            echo $text;

        }
        else{
            echo " </br></br><h1> Please select month and year!! </h1> ";
        }
        ?>
        <div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 100%; height:900px;"></div>
```

Comment: _Seems like the sql is fine..._ No.."mysql_*" functions are deprecated... also your question is not clear...

Comment: i tried those "mysql_*" on my other pages and yet it works fine

Comment: _i tried those "mysql_*"..._ Again "mysql_*" functions are deprecated..

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.0+.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But why on my other php files it works just fine and shows the graphs?

Comment: config2.php

`<?php
//DB details
$dbHost     = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName     = 'lcho_login';

//Create connection and select DB
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if($db->connect_error){
    die("Unable to connect database: " . $db->connect_error);
}
?>`

and now im using this instead of the "mysql_*"

Comment: ` <?php
                       include 'config2.php';
                            
                        $sql=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(`deng_case_ind1`) AS ind_num FROM lcho_dengue_cases2 WHERE `date` between '". $dFrom ."' and '".$dTo."' ");
        
                        $indicator10='ind_num'; // name column in the table
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {
                         
                          echo $row['ind_num'];
                            
                        }
                    ?>`

Comment: do you still need help with this question? if so, are there any errors in the browser's console? if not, will you please share the javascript code, after the page has loaded and the php has completed? (right click the page and select view source / view page source)